# how to tell tomcat be verbose while deploying war

Tags: tomcat, deployment, tomcat6, war

I have war application that takes quite a while to deploy in tomcat 6. it has relatively large number of jars and bean files etc. right now it takes to much time to get deployed. I have tried

1. `jstack` of `PID` of tomcat and get the thread dump to see if any useful infomation can be found.
2. And i also looked at log files of tomcat see if anything useful i can pick up, not much of help from these options

Is there a way to tell to print much of the verbose detail in tomcat console while deployment / unwar is going on?

Comment: What do the log files of tomcat say ? Are there any errors ?

Comment: during deployment (war) i dont see anything printed

Answer (score 1):

Set the application level logging to DEBUG and you should be getting all the logs about which bean getting initialized, which jar is being loaded and so on.
It should be more than enough - at least it is in my case